# chrome content script onclick event

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension and cannot seem to understand how to implement the following scenario:

- user is on page X
- user clicks on the extension's button

  - something happens (specifically, user is redirected to some url)

here's the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "my title"
    },

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["myscript.js"]
      }
  ],


  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "https://*/*"
  ]

}
```

and here's myscript.js:

```
alert('entered myscript.js..');

function doMagic()
{
    alert('extension button clicked!!');
}

chrome.extension.onClicked.addListener(doMagic);
```

i know im missing something really obvious, but cant seem to figure it out from the docs, other sites, etc.!!

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a `content_script`, you really only need those if have to have access to the HTML of the tab.

Use a [background_page](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) for the `onClicked` listener and [chrome.tabs.update](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update) to redirect the page.

```
function doMagic(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: 'http://www.google.com' });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(doMagic);
```

Comment: thanks...that's what i *just* started trying, but for the life of me I cannot redirect the tab's url!!!  for e.g.: this works fine:      chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com"});    but this doesn't:        chrome.tabs.update({url:"http://www.google.com"});

Comment: I added some example code that should redirect the current tab when the browserAction button is clicked.

Comment: ahhh! thanks a lot!! this works great!...I have one more question though: how does one access the url of the current tab?

Comment: found it, it's simply tab.url...going crazy here....thanks for all your help!!i have to say, chrome's docs suck big time

Comment: I'd just like to say that the [Chrome documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) is fantastic, provided it's read properly to learn the quirks. I've very rarely found something missing and never anything to be incorrect. Google are very good at writing helpful documentation and spend a lot of time and money on it.

Comment: I haven't found `chrome.extension.onClicked.addListener` in the docs. Seems like you can't do this on a background page.

Comment: I didn't even notice that the `onClicked` listener wasn't using the correct API. I fixed my example code.